# Calling particular tabs of same tab bar controller based on different buttons from navigation controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

My Application's Workflow:

[image: Application Workflow]

Here, I have 1 one **Main Navigation Controller**.Then, it push to **1 Tabbar Controller** & **2 View Controllers**.
Main Tabbar Controller has **2 different navigation controllers** for individual functionalities.

Now, I want to navigate to **Main Tabbar** from button 1 & button 2.

When I pressed, button 1, it will shift to 2nd Tab & when I pressed button 2, it will shift to 3rd tab as I described in an image.

I am using **`self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];`** code for shifting tab.

It's shifting, but not calling **`ViewDidLoad`** method of that class & not loading data accordingly.

So, how to call particular tab based on button's click ??

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = yourIndex;` as Foram Mukund Shah has said.

But, as you want to change the index, you need to write this code in `viewDidAppear` rather than on `viewDidLoad` it is not changing because you are trying to change index before your tabbar is loaded.

So, please try to put your code in `viewDidAppear`.

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try with following snippet once

```
<tabbar_controller_object>.selectedIndex = <YOUR_tab_no_to_select>;
```